# Не могу присвоить значение из списка переменной

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
firstTreatment = inputString.split("Доставлено")
for x in firstTreatment:
    x = x.split()
    b = x[3]

    print(b)
```

Выдает ошибку list index out of range

Comment: ну хорошо. вы список свой на печать выведите. что там получается? какой-то дебагинг вы же должны сами делать.

Comment: делал, выводит правильный список, по типу ['Привет', 'меня', 'зовут', 'Андрей']

Comment: В правилах сайта сказано про минимально воспроизводый код. Пока же: `NameError: name 'inputString' is not defined`

Comment: Я не могу воспроизводить этот код, да и от его наличия и неналичия не меняется ровным счетом ничего. Переменная inputString считывается с экрана.

Comment: Давайте начнём с того, в какой строчке кода вами приложенного возникает ошибка?

Comment: в 4, где используется индекс списка

Comment: а `firstTreatment` не содержит какой-нибудь пустой список? скажем после слова "Доставлено` ентер и при сплите получается еще пустой список? Гадаю )))

Comment: Используете пайчарм? Запустите ваше приложение в режиме отладки и увидите состояние переменных на момент ошибки в вашей программе. Если нет то тогда выведите все переменные в терминал и посмотрите их содержимое перед возникновением ошибки. Результатом можете поделиться тут

Comment: содержится, а как от него избавиться?

Comment: ну можно в цикле проверять `if len(x.strip())>0:` перед остальными операциями, что-бы пустые и пробельные списки пропускать.